# Rails Error Messages too Long for Command Window

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

Something is wrong with my Rails app because when I run bundle install, I receive a long list of errors, part of which keep repeating (block in resolve_requirement).  The list is so long, when I scroll to the top of my command window (in Windows), I can't see the start of the error messages (ie what requirement is causing the problem).

Also, when I got into my log > development file the errors aren't logged there.  Is there a setting I can change to help so I can either see the start of the error messages or I can see the error messages in my log > development file?

Comment: I believe the development log file only shows output from your rails app.  I don't think there is a way to get `bundle` output to show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run the command

```
bundle install > output.txt
```

you can read the output in a text editor

Comment: Of course there are other ways to approach this.  For instance you could the Screen Buffer Size value in CMD.exe's properties to a higher value.

Comment: hmmm.  do you know how i change the screen buffer size?  the output file created, but only with the first two lines: Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index for http://gemcutter.org/

Comment: in cmd?  On Windows 7, I can right click on the title bar, go to properties.  It brings up a settings panel.  From there go to the layout tab and change the height of your Screen Buffer Size to a very large number.  Good luck!